# Why can I invoke a function via a pointer with too many arguments?

Tags: c, function-pointers, calling-convention

Say I have this function:

```
int func2() {
    printf("func2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I declare a pointer:

```
int (*fp)(double);
```

This should point to a function that takes a `double` argument and returns an `int`.

`func2` does NOT have any argument, but still when I write:

```
fp = func2;
fp(2);
```

(with `2` being just an arbitrary number), func2` is invoked correctly.

Why is that? Is there no meaning to the number of parameters I declare for a function pointer?

Comment: The short answer is "declaring a function with no arguments... and then deliberately passing an argument... is just wrong".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, there is a meaning.  In C (but *not* in C++), a function declared with an empty set of parentheses means it takes an *unspecified* number of parameters.  When you do this, you're preventing the compiler from checking the number and types of arguments; it's a holdover from before the C language was standardized by ANSI and ISO.

Failing to call a function with the proper number and types of arguments results in *undefined behavior*.  If you instead explicitly declare your function to take zero parameters by using a parameter list of `void`, then the compiler will give you a warning when you assign a function pointer of the wrong type:

```
int func1();  // declare function taking unspecified parameters
int func2(void);  // declare function taking zero parameters
...
// No warning, since parameters are potentially compatible; calling will lead
// to undefined behavior
int (*fp1)(double) = func1;
...
// warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
int (*fp2)(double) = func2;
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to explicitly declare the parameter, otherwise you'll get undefined behavior :)

```
int func2(double x)
{
    printf("func2(%lf)\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```