# What does void*(*void)(void*) stands for?

Tags: c++, void, void-pointers

And what's the difference between

```
void*(*void)(void*)
```

and

```
void*(*voi)(void*)
```

and when to use it?

Comment: I see no difference, exept a typo (voi)

Comment: Don't you have a typo: 'voi' instead of 'void'?

Comment: well `void*(void)(void)` doesn't compile, because it tries to declare a function that returns a `void*` named `void` and you can't use keywords of the language as names.

Comment: The formatting is making the \* get lost

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You were putting something more, that wasn't in the OP. That's why I rolled back.

Comment: Yes, the typo shouldn't have been fixed, otherwise the formatting is making people miss the point

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Found a simpler way to clarify with an edit ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well `void*(void)(void)` doesn't compile, because it tries to declare a function that returns a void* named void and you can't use keywords of the language as names.

you can't declare an int named void either (`int void=5;` doesn't work of course).

Now `voi` is a valid identifier and you can name a function `voi`.

Trying to get at what you're actually asking the difference between.

`void(*name)(void);` and `void(name)(void);` is that one declares a function and the other declares a function pointer.
In fact the brackets on the second example don't do anything. `void(name)(void);` is the same as `void name(void);`.

However when declaring function pointers the brackets are needed or the `*` will bind left to the return type.

Anyway, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, so you're best off searching the site for other questions regarding function pointers. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140045/function-pointer-declaration) that also explains why using `void(name)(void)` can be different from `void(name)()`.